# Why does s7="hello",'world'; print(s7) in Python emit ('hello', 'world')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to experiment something with strings.

I have below commands.

```
s7="hello",'world'
print(s7)
```

Output was : `('hello', 'world')`

As per my understanding, it should not print angular braces and it should not print hello in single quotes. Could you help me in understanding this?

Comment: You are building a tuple containing two strings. Your assignment is equivalent to `s7=("hello",'world')`. The fact that you can omit the `()` is syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned not 1, but *2* strings (in a tuple) to `s7`, which explains how it was printed.

```
s7 = "\"hello\",'world'"
```

seems like it would assign the string you want.  (Note the use of `\"`to indicate a `"` *inside* of a string surrounded by `"`s, as @NielsHenkens points out.)

Comment: To add to this answer: the `\ ` is called an 'escape character'. It makes sure that the character that follows it, will be used 'as is'. So `\"` will make sure that the double quotation is treated as part of the string, instead of the second quotation that signals the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not angular braces. They are parentheses, and they indicate that what you are printing is a *tuple*. A tuple is kind of sequence, in this case a pair of strings.

Your first string is `"hello"`, and your second string is `'world'`.

You could have expressed them as `'hello'` and `"world"` and produced exactly the same strings. The quote marks (either kind) are there to indicate the content of the string, but they are not *part* of the content of the string.